# addPeriodicSync to trigger an initial sync

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Is it possible to trigger a sync process immediately after the creation of a periodic sync?

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, DbContentProvider.AUTHORITY, true);
// Make this run a sync job...
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, DbContentProvider.AUTHORITY, bundle, 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger the sync to happen immediately

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, DbContentProvider.AUTHORITY, bundle);
```